# Flask logs everyone out when ever I make changes to the code

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am using Flask and Nginx on my production server and Flask seems to log everyone out whenever I make a change to the code. I realize the reason for this, but I was wondering if there is any way to prevent this. I am using a proxy with Nginx if that makes any difference, I could easily switch back to uwsgi if that will fix the problem but I would prefer to keep my configuration the way it is.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: If there is any confusion, I am trying to find a way to keep everyone logged in when I make changes to my code.

Comment: Flask does not have a concept of "logged in", that is a concept that you create on top of Flask (either on your own, or using something like [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)). Therefore, the answer to this question is completely dependent on how you implemented a user being "logged in". Can you describe how you implement this in your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are signed against the `app.secret_key` so perhaps you're automatically generating a new secret key each time you launch your app?

Answer (score 0):

Auto-reload is enabled [only in debug mode, according to the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/). If you disable debug mode, this should prevent server restarts from auto-reloads.

Comment: I know this, I am wondering if there is a way to prevent flask from logging all my users out when I make a change.